# How can I switch the build configuration from "Debug" to "Release" in JetBrains IDE Rider with the new UI?

Tags: .net, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-rider

I have configured two build configurations in my solution file like so:

```
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
```

In the old Rider UI, it was really easy to switch between the two:

[image]

Screenshot is from the official documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Build_Configurations.html#solution

However, since turning on the in the new UI (which is still in Beta right now), this dropdown is missing and I can't find a way to change the build configuration. How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to *Build → Change Solution configuration...*:
[image]

In the following dialog, you can choose the build configuration:
[image]

You can also click *Show Configuration on Toolbar* to bring it back to the toolbar.

Edit: With the latest version of Rider 2023.1 (tested with Build #RD-231.8109.212, built on April 4, 2023), the toolbar now shows up as expected:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can change the configuration like suggested. However, even if I enable the "Show Configuration in Toolbar" option, it doesn't show up in the toolbar..

Comment: Perhaps a bug in the version you have?  I've switched over to the beta UI to check and I have the same view as @mu88 shows.

Comment: Same problem here. When you click on the toolbar as per your screenshot above, only the last entry in the list exists: "Show Configuration on Toolbar" (which toggles whether the dropdown is shown in the top menu bar). What is missing are the menu entries to "Edit Solution Configurations...", toggle between Debug and Release, etc.

Comment: I had the same issue as @miguno. Turned out it worked when I opened it as an sln, but failed as a csproj.